# Choose appropriate preposition when talking about feelings "To" vs "With"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english

How do I know when to use “ to “ or with” when talking about feelings?
For example

> “ She is rude **to** me”

and

> “ Are you upset **with** me”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is "by consulting a dictionary". The use of prepositions is one of the most idiosyncratic parts of English (and other languages') grammar; and often the choice of preposition is not predictable by logic or meaning, but just happens to be what it is.

In your example, "rude to (someone)" makes sense because rudeness is about behaviour towards other people: if there are no other people involved, behaviour can't be rude.

"Sad with (someone)" is not somethign I recognise as a common expression. If I heard it I would most likely interpret it as "sad in company with (someone)", i.e. both being sad together.

I would however say "angry with (someone)", meaning that the anger is caused by the persons actions. But the angry behaviour is not necessarily towards the person, but might be kept internal, or expressed to another person.

But arguments of this kind, though they might seem to make sense, are not reliable for determining usage. If I get angry with somebody (i.e. about what they have done) and go and shout at them, it is still not idiomatic to say that I am "angry to them".

Answer (score 0):

Generally use "with" when describing how someone's actions have affected you. For example:

- "I'm happy with Rick."
- "I sympathize with her."

Use "to" when describing an action you perpetrate on someone and when someone perpetrates an action upon you; for example:

- "I'm always rude to Andy."
- "Andy is always nice to me."